# Copying Headers from CSV in Python not Working-- Delimiter Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to copy headers from one Python file to another and it's splitting the headers into individual characters, one character for a column. I'm not sure why.

I've read through StackOverflow but couldn't find a question/solution to this problem.

first.csv file data

```
Date,Data
1/2/2019,a
12/1/2018,b
11/3/2018,c
```

Python Code

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_ = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y_%m_%d')

with open('first.csv', 'r') as full_file, open('second.csv' + '_' + date_ + '.csv', 'w') as past_10_days:
writer = csv.writer(past_10_days)
writer.writerow(next(full_file)) #copy headers over from original file
for row in csv.reader(full_file): #run through remaining rows
    if datetime.strptime(row[0],'%m/%d/%Y') > datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10):  #write rows where timestamp is greater than today - 10
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Result I get:

```
D,a,t,e,D,a,t,a

1/2/2019,a
```

I'd like the result to just be

```
Date,Data
1/2/2019,a
```

Am I just missing setting an option? This is Python 3+

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps define your csv reader before reading the first row? Then use your reader to get the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
writer.writerow(next(full_file))
```

To

```
writer.writerow(next(csv.reader(full_file)))
```

Your code is reading `full_file` as a text file, not as a CSV, so you'll just get the characters.

Ideally, as roganjosh pointed out, you should simply define the reader once, so the code should look like this:

```
reader = csv.reader(full_file)
writer.writerow(next(reader))
for row in reader:
    if datetime.strptime(row[0],'%m/%d/%Y') > datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10):  
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Gross. The OP goes on to define another reader and then iterate through it again. This throws the `reader` away. Just define a single `reader` object at the start, assign it to a name, and use that :) There's no need to be packing all this into a single line.

Comment: Agreed, this was simply to highlight the issue.

Comment: Thanks guys, both solutions worked, I went ahead and defined a single reader object.